# Retrofit 1.9 Error on Callback

Tags: java, android, json, callback, retrofit

I am getting the following error when trying to run my Retrofit GET call and the error occurs on the callback:

```
E/roboguice: Throwable caught during background processing
         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IMyClient.getUser: Must have return type or Callback as last argument, not both.
             at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(RestMethodInfo.java:107)
             at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseResponseType(RestMethodInfo.java:267)
             at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.<init>(RestMethodInfo.java:97)
             at retrofit.RestAdapter.getMethodInfo(RestAdapter.java:213)
             at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:236)
             at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
             at $Proxy15.getUser(Unknown Source)
             at client.MyClient.getUser(MyClient.java:111)
             at task.UserProfileTask.call(UserProfileTask.java:41)
             at task.UserProfileTask.call(UserProfileTask.java:22)
             at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask$SafeAsyncTaskAndroidCallable.doInBackground(SafeAsyncTask.java:163)
             at roboguice.util.AndroidCallableWrapper.doDoInBackgroundThread(AndroidCallableWrapper.java:113)
             at roboguice.util.AndroidCallableWrapper.run(AndroidCallableWrapper.java:41)
             at roboguice.util.AndroidCallable.run(AndroidCallable.java:20)
             at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
             at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
             at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
             at roboguice.util.AndroidCallable.<init>(AndroidCallable.java:12)
             at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask$SafeAsyncTaskAndroidCallable.<init>(SafeAsyncTask.java:160)
             at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask.newTask(SafeAsyncTask.java:156)
             at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask.future(SafeAsyncTask.java:66)
             at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask.execute(SafeAsyncTask.java:94)
             at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask.execute(SafeAsyncTask.java:90)
             at ui.fragment.AccountFragment.onViewCreated(AccountFragment.java:122)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1127)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:604)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
             at roboguice.activity.RoboActionBarActivity.onStart(RoboActionBarActivity.java:106)
             at ui.activity.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:270)
             at ui.activity.AccountActivity.onStart(AccountActivity.java:60)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This pattern works fine with my login but i am new to Retrofit and cant seem to locate the exact issue here.

My code for IMyClient.Java:

```
    @GET("/persons")
List<UserProfile> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String token, Callback<List<UserProfile>> callback);
```

Before adding the callback this worked fine, but of course i need to be able to access the response to parse the Json.

In my MyClient i create an instance of IMyClient and that looks like this:

```
public List<UserProfile> getUser(String token, Callback<List<UserProfile>> callback) {
    return client.getUser(token, callback);
}
```

I have the Callback laid out to that of what i found in the Retrofit 1.9 documentation and how it is working with my login:

```
@Override
public List<UserProfile> call() throws Exception {
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    String response = "";
    client.getUser(token, new Callback<List<UserProfile>>(){

        @Override
        public void success(List<UserProfile> profile, Response response) {
            Object data = profile;
            Object data1 = response;

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            OttoBusSingleton.getInstance().post(error);
        }
    } );

    return new ArrayList<UserProfile>();
}
```

In this Callback i would like to be able to access the response and get the JSON from it. The UserProfile is a model i am using to set all the JSON objects to.

I am not sure why it is working with the login but not working here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your last code snippet looks very strange. How it should work? you allways return empty array and do nothing with real response.

Comment: The two objects in response are simply breakpoints to see that the response is being returned. The answer to my problem is below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the provided stacktrace:

> Must have return type or Callback as last argument, not both.

It mean this if you want to make request async

```
@GET("/persons")
void getUser(@Header("Authorization") String token, Callback<List<UserProfile>> callback);
```

or if you want to make it sync

```
@GET("/persons")
List<UserProfile> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

Comment: Thank you, this turned out to be my issue and was something i simply overlooked!